# Provide static interface to access Beans with Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have created many `MessageChannel`s, each wrapped in separate Object `Sender`.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketSendersConfig {

    @Bean
    public Sender heartBeatSender(
            HeartBeatWebSocketChannel channel,
            @Qualifier("mappingJackson2MessageConverter") MessageConverter converter
    ) {
        return createSender(channel, converter);
    }

    @Bean
    public Sender upperCaseSender(
           UpperCaseWebSocketChannel channel, 
           @Qualifier("mappingJackson2MessageConverter") MessageConverter converter  
    ) {
        return createSender(channel, converter);
    }

    @Bean
    public Sender ...

    ...
```

Now if I want send message via sender (MessageChannel) called `heartBeat` I can do this:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("heartBeat") heartBeatSender;

sendToHeartBeat(Message<?> msg) {
    heartBeatSender.send(msg);
}
```

I want to get rid off the autowiring and access chosen Sender (MessageChannel) via static method:

```
@Service
public class WebSocketSenders {

    private static Sender heartBeatSender;
    private static Sender upperCaseSender;
    private static Sender lowerCaseSender;

    @Autowired
    public WebSocketSendersAccessor(
            @Qualifier("heartBeatSender") Sender heartBeatSender,
            @Qualifier("upperCaseSender") Sender upperCaseSender,
            @Qualifier("lowerCaseSender") Sender lowerCaseSender
    ) {
        this.heartBeatSender = heartBeatSender;
        this.upperCaseSender = upperCaseSender;
        this.lowerCaseSender = lowerCaseSender;
    }

    public static Sender HEART_BEAT() {
        return heartBeatSender;
    }

    public static Sender UPPER_CASE() {
        return upperCaseSender;
    }

    public static Sender LOWER_CASE() {
        return lowerCaseSender;
    }
}
```

Now I can access it via static methods:

```
@Autowired
WebSocketSendersAccessor accessor;

sendToHeartBeat(Message<?> msg) {
    accessor.HEART_BEAT().send(msg);
}
```

Now I must autowire the accessor class.
How to improve this by getting rid of autowiring accessor class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `InitializingBean` interface:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class WebSocketSenders  implements InitializingBean {

    @Qualifier("heartBeatSender") private final Sender heartBeatSender;
    @Qualifier("upperCaseSender") private final Sender upperCaseSender;
    @Qualifier("lowerCaseSender") private final Sender lowerCaseSender;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        SomeClass.staticHeartBeatSender = heartBeatSender;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
class SomeClass {
   static Sender staticHeartBeatSender;
   sendToHeartBeat(Message<?> msg) {
      staticHeartBeatSender.send(msg);
   }
}
```